# Simplify the Difference Quotient when $f(x)= \frac{15}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Simplify the Difference Quotient when $f(x)= \frac{15}{x^2}$. The difference quotient formula is $\frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{ h}$.

I understand how to simplify basic difference quotient equations. In this case, you start with the formula: $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{15}{{(x+h)}^2}-\frac{15}{x^2}}{h}$. The answer to the problem is $\displaystyle\frac{-15(h+2x)}{x^2(h+x)^2}$.

I have tried multiplying by the conjugate and the Least Common Denominator, but my algebra skills aren't leading me to the correct answer. Please help!

Comment: Least Common Denominator should work. Can you show your steps here?

Comment: Simplify the Difference Quotient when $f(x)= \frac{15}{x^2}$. The difference quotient formula is $\frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{ h}$.

I understand how to simplify basic difference quotient equations. In this case, you start with the formula: $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{15}{{(x+h)}^2}-\frac{15}{x^2}}{h}$. The answer to the problem is $\displaystyle\frac{-15(h+2x)}{x^2(h+x)^2}$.

I have tried multiplying by the conjugate and the Least Common Denominator, but my algebra skills aren't leading me to the correct answer. Please help!

Comment: Question should be clearly written

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{15}{x^2}$

Now

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\frac{15}{(x+h)^2}-\frac{15}{x^2}}{h}$

$=\frac{15}{h}[\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}]$

$=\frac{15}{h}[\frac{x^2-(x+h)^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}]$

$=\frac{15}{h}[\frac{x^2-x^2-2xh-h^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}]$

$=\frac{-15}{h}[\frac{2xh+h^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}]$

$=-15[\frac{2x+h}{x^2(x+h)^2}]$

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I was stuck on the second and third steps (brain freeze?) but your steps helped me work through it. :)

Comment: If you liked it then vote for my solution

Answer (score 0):

Cross multiplication gives $\frac{15x^2-15(x+h)^2}{x^2(x+h)^2h}$, then expand the numerator.

Comment: Thank you John McGee. This helps a lot!

Comment: PS- I'm creating an account with this site and will up vote your answer soon. :)